# Random numbers algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I need to generate random numbers in groups: 100, 500, 1000 and 10000 numbers uniforms and gaussians. This is necessary for create some histograms and other statistic stuff.

The condition is not to use python's native random function, so I was thinking to use this method (linear congruential generator): `Xn+1 ≡ (aXn + c) mod m`. Here I need 4 variables.
Can someone please tell me how can i implement this algorithm? I assume that the **m** variable the first time is **100**

Comment: I doubt you will find a good linear congruential generator with m=100. You should look at generators with much larger m. Even better, implement Mersenne Twister if you have time. Then use other techniques to get the final result into the uniform range you want or to convert the output of your generator to gaussians (there have been various previous questions here on similar topics, so look them up).

Comment: i have tried this:
n=1
c=3
x=0
m=100

for i in range(100):
    x = (a*x+c) % m

Comment: thank you so much david, i will check out

Comment: @DavidK python's native PRNG **is** Mersenne Twister.

Comment: @pjs  Glad to learn that. It might be relevant to know _why_ the condition not to use the native function was imposed. If it was "I want you to have the experience of implementing a random number generator rather than just calling `random.randint()`" then any good RNG should be fair game to implement. If it was "I want to you implement an RNG that isn't Mersenne Twister so we can compare the two algorithms" then of course one cannot use MT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already know that this is [Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), so what is so hard to read it up?

It tells you the formula you already know [image] and an explanation how you should select them:

> The period of a general LCG is at most m, and for some choices of
>   factor a much less than that. Provided that the offset c is nonzero,
>   the LCG will have a full period for all seed values if and only if:
>
> 1) c and m are relatively prime
>
> 2) a - 1 is divisible by all prime factors of m
>
> 3) a - 1 is a multiple of 4 if m is a multiple of 4.

They even give you some examples of these values in the table below. This is more than enough to implement a simple function:

```
def LCG(seed, n, a=1664525, c=1013904223, m=2**32):
    numbers = []
    for i in xrange(n):
        seed = (a * seed + c) % m
        numbers.append(seed)

    return numbers

print LCG(3, 5)
```

Comment: Thank you so much salvador, I really really apreciate it